# Glitch in 'Open with...'

Tags: file, ui

I want to change all media apps to open with VLC.

So I right click on one, get info, open with:

But now this:

[image]

And I only have one VLC on my system:

ps-MacBook-Air:~ pi$ sudo find / -iname "VLC.app"
/Applications/VLC.app

Is this a microscopic bug?

And who is at fault? I suspect maybe VLC needs to register somewhere as a media player and maybe it has registered twice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a well known bug in `LaunchServices`.

You need to rebuild the database using this command:

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Versions/A/Support/lsregister -kill -r -domain local -domain user;killall Finder;echo "Open With has been rebuilt, Finder will relaunch"
```

then

```
killall Finder
```

Once you have done that you will only have one entry for each application.

Here is the command split onto multiple lines

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/\
LaunchServices.framework/Versions/A/Support/\
lsregister -kill -r -domain local -domain user
```

(Notice the `\` characters that allow a command to stretch across physical lines in `bash`.)